# MacOS Big Sur : impossible to compile with a C++ code with Intel compiler

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, compilation, intel, icc

I have just migrated from Catalina to Big Sur and I have issues when compiling a simple C++ code with Intel icpc compiler (version 2020 Update 4).

With brew's GNU version `g++-4.9`, it doesn't work also but compiles fine with brew's `g++-6` and `g++-10`.

Before the Big Sur update, I had no problems with `icpc` on Catalina.

For Intel, I thought that installing CTL (Command Tools line) version 11 would be sufficient but this is not the case : indeed, it is misssing the package `Headers .pkg` in `CTL version 11`: how can I do without these Headers now?

For the instant, I get these errors :

```
icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -xHost -qopenmp -Wall -c -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.301/mac/mkl/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 -mkl=parallel main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h(311),
                 from /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.301/mac/compiler/include/math.h(177),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath(304),
                 from TSAF.h(1),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(903): error: type name is not allowed
      __is_function(_Tp)
                    ^

In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h(311),
                 from /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.301/mac/compiler/include/math.h(177),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath(304),
                 from TSAF.h(1),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(903): error: identifier "__is_function" is undefined
      __is_function(_Tp)
      ^

In file included from TSAF.h(2),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(903): error: type name is not allowed
      __is_function(_Tp)
                    ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "std::__1::is_function<_Tp> [with _Tp=long long ****************************************************************************************************]" at line 1360
            instantiation of class "std::__1::__decay<_Up, true> [with _Up=long long ****************************************************************************************************]" at line 1373
            instantiation of class "std::__1::decay<_Tp> [with _Tp=long long ****************************************************************************************************]" at line 2119
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp=long long ****************************************************************************************************, _Up=long long ****************************************************************************************************]" at line 2118
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp=long long ***************************************************************************************************, _Up=long long ***************************************************************************************************]" at line 2118
            [ 97 instantiation contexts not shown ]
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp=long long *, _Up=long long *]" at line 2118
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp=long long, _Up=long long]" at line 874 of "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono"
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<std::__1::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>, std::__1::chrono::duration<_Rep2, _Period2>> [with _Rep1=long long, _Period1=std::__1::micro, _Rep2=long long, _Period2=std::__1::micro]" at line 2112
            instantiation of class "std::__1::common_type<_Tp> [with _Tp=std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::micro>]" at line 1101 of "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono"
            instantiation of class "std::__1::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period> [with _Rep=long long, _Period=std::__1::micro]" at line 1575 of "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono"

In file included from TSAF.h(2),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(903): error: type name is not allowed
      __is_function(_Tp)
...
```

Why the `Headers .pkg` doesn't appear anymore with Command Tool Lines v11?

How could I circumvent this issue?

Comment: This seems to be mostly the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216558/macos-big-sur-impossible-to-compile-with-a-c-code-with-intel-compiler-and-gc (which you've already deleted).  Generally you should [edit] your existing question to include more details, not delete and re-post a version with slightly different wording but the same errors.

Comment: @PeterCordes . I have updated my question since I have solved partially the original issue with `GNU brew's g++-6` and `g++-10` but not for the intel compilation on macOS Big Sur. Hoping this problem of compilation with Intel compiler deserves to be explored.

Comment: Ok, if you solved the original and deleted instead of posting a self-answer, and this is a different question, I guess that's ok.

Comment: I have re-applied the fixes from the last question to this one. In particular, it appears that you are committed to misusing the formatting tools, and are not taking reasonable notice of good edits to your questions. The copious use of code/IO formatting as a general highlighter is semantically incorrect. Please refrain from using this formatting device in this way.